# How to execute a code only once after a certain condition has been met?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

What I'd like to happen is to swap the content of 2 divs once the window has reached a certain width (1023px) but I don't want it to keep running the swapping code every time I resize the window after it has already reached that width (1023px):

```
$(window).resize(function() {

  if($(window).width() <= 1023) {      

    var $left_col = $('.about-left-col').html();
    var $right_col = $('.about-right-col').html();

    $('.about-right-col').html($left_col);
    $('.about-left-col').html($right_col);

  } 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `==`

```
$(window).resize(function() {

  if($(window).width() == 1023) {      

    var $left_col = $('.about-left-col').html();
    var $right_col = $('.about-right-col').html();

    $('.about-right-col').html($left_col);
    $('.about-left-col').html($right_col);

  } 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a simple variable (above you resize function) and check against it.

```
var wasResized = false;
```

Set it to true when resizing and add a check to you condition if it is true/false.

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable to store the state

```
var notChanged = true;

$(window).resize(function() {

  if($(window).width() <= 1023) {      
    if(notChanged) {//test if its not changed
    var $left_col = $('.about-left-col').html();
    var $right_col = $('.about-right-col').html();

    $('.about-right-col').html($left_col);
    $('.about-left-col').html($right_col);
     notChanged = false;//set it to false so the code doesn't trigger anymore 
    }
  } 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
$(window).resize(function() {

      if($(window).width() <= 1023) {      

        var $left_col = $('.about-left-col').html();
        var $right_col = $('.about-right-col').html();

        if($('.about-right-col').html() != $left_col){
            $('.about-right-col').html($left_col);
            $('.about-left-col').html($right_col);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
      } 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, have a counter on function execution using a closure and proceed as you need.

```js
$(window).resize(reposition);

function reposition = ({
  var count = 0;

  return function() {
    if (count !== 0) {
      return;
    }
    if ($(window).width() <= 1023) {
      var $left_col = $('.about-left-col').html();
      var $right_col = $('.about-right-col').html();

      $('.about-right-col').html($left_col);
      $('.about-left-col').html($right_col);
      count++;
    }

  };
})();
```